# Name of kid's book about rabbit who nibbles hole in shirt

Tags: identification-request

I am looking for a children's book that has one page with a picture of the rabbit sitting on a boy's lap. The rabbit looks to be sleeping but it is actually nibbling a hole in the boy's shirt.

I remember having it read to me around 1960. I don't think I have seen it in the last 58 years.

Edit:
The book was in English and was illustrated throughout.